# Can't run Cassandra on Docker with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, docker, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, apache-zeppelin

I have a Zeppelin notebook running on Docker. I have the following code using Cassandra:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

val cqlContext = new CassandraSQLContext(sc)

cqlContext.sql("select * from demo.table").collect.foreach(println)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
cqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext@395e28a8
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot build a cluster without contact points
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2199)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3936)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4806)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraCatalog.lookupRelation(CassandraCatalog.scala:28)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext$$anon$2.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$OverrideCatalog$$super$lookupRelation(CassandraSQLContext.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$$anonfun$lookupRelation$3.apply(Catalog.scala:137)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.OverrideCatalog$class.lookupRelation(Catalog.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraSQLContext$$anon$2.lookupRelation(CassandraSQLContext.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$5.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$5.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:162)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildrenDown(TreeNode.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed(SQLContext.scala:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.withCachedData$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:412)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.withCachedData(SQLContext.scala:412)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(SQLContext.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:418)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan(SQLContext.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan(SQLContext.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.collect(SchemaRDD.scala:444)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:45)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:47)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:49)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:51)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:53)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:55)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:57)
    at <init>(<console>:59)
    at .<init>(<console>:63)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:705)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:669)
    at com.nflabs.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:541)
    at com.nflabs.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:517)
    at com.nflabs.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:510)
    at com.nflabs.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:40)
    at com.nflabs.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:76)
    at com.nflabs.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:246)
    at com.nflabs.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:152)
    at com.nflabs.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot build a cluster without contact points
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.checkNotEmpty(Cluster.java:116)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:108)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:177)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:1109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.DefaultConnectionFactory$.createCluster(CassandraConnectionFactory.scala:78)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(CassandraConnector.scala:167)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:162)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$2.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:162)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.createNewValueAndKeys(RefCountedCache.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.RefCountedCache.acquire(RefCountedCache.scala:56)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.openSession(CassandraConnector.scala:73)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:99)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraCatalog$$anon$1.load(CassandraCatalog.scala:22)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraCatalog$$anon$1.load(CassandraCatalog.scala:19)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
    ... 92 more
```

From the Docker command line I ran `docker pull cassandra` but still the issue persists.

What should I do to be able to use Cassandra?

Comment: You just used `docker pull`?

Comment: Did you use `docker run` command to run the cassandra container?

Comment: Yes, `docker run` and then `docker attach`

Comment: Sorry, actually I use `docker start`, not `docker run`. So I did `docker start  bdu_spark2` and `docker attach bdu_spark2`.

Answer (score 1):

For spark to connect to cassandra cluster you have to provide the one of the node of cassandra cluster in spark conf as follows:

```
conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
```

Comment: If I add this to the code: 
`sc.stop()`


`val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myApp").setMaster("local")`


`conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")`


`val sc = new SparkContext(conf)`, then I get the same error.

Comment: Is your cassandra cluster running on localhost?

Comment: Actually, it's running on Docker, that's on IP `192.168.99.100`, but if I use this address in `conf.set` I get the error: 
`java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.0.1}:9042`

Comment: Can you try setting the IP of your docker image instead of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue `Cannot build a cluster without contact points` and managed to solve it by setting the `SparkConf()` as follows:

```
conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName("MyApp") \
    .setMaster("spark://127.0.0.1:7077") \
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
```

So, a basic Spark < 2.0 program - in Python - that connects with a local Cassandra should look like:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName("PySpark Cassandra Test") \
    .setMaster("spark://127.0.0.1:7077") \
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

sc = SparkContext('local', conf=conf)
sql = SQLContext(sc)

test = sql.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").\
               load(keyspace="mykeyspace", table="mytable")

test.collect()
```